# How to read data from xcel first colum by python

Tags: python, xlrd

How can i read data from first column in excel. My data in excel is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1XTp.jpg)

```
import xlrd 

loc = ("my path") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        print(sheet.cell_value(i,0))
```

> > Output:[is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emzDM.jpg)

So I want to read only str column not a float

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any integer type for cells, we just have float. To convert the floating number to an integer just use int as:

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print (int(sheet.cell_value(i,0)))
```

and subsequently for the string as :

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print (str(sheet.cell_value(i,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this:

```py
xlsx_file = pd.read_excel(your_file)
xlsx_file.name_of_column 

#create a list with the data of your column
list_name_of_column = xlsx_file.name_of_column.to_list()
```

Now you can loop over your list and [convert the datatype](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-python/).

With int(), str(),... or what ever you desire!